# How do I input numbers in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to input numbers in arr[n][m], but there is the problem, that numbers in an array should be constants, that's why I tried to do this:

```
int n,m;
cin>>n>>m;
int *arr= new int[n][m];
```

But it doesn't work for `m`, what should I do?

Comment: You should use `std::vector`.

Comment: When you say that it "doesn't work", I assume you are seeing a compile-time error about unknown array dimensions?  Could you please include the exact error message from the compiler?

Comment: You need to understand how arrays are created and handled without `cin` first.

Comment: error: the value of ‘m’ is not usable in a constant expression that's the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are suggested to use `std::vector`. But as per question to allocated 2-D array you should do.

```
int row,column;
cin>>row>>column;
int** arr = new int*[row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    arr[i] = new int[column];
```

[Go there for vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)